# Objects are not valid as a React child - Confusing Error

Tags: reactjs

I have a very basic React app setup. I am getting an error I do not understand. This is the error in full:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {posts}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in PostList (at App.js:17)
    in div (at App.js:15)
    in App (at index.js:7)
▶ 25 stack frames were collapsed.
./src/index.js
src/index.js:7
   4 | import App from './App';
   5 | import posts from './posts.json'
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(<App posts={posts}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
   8 | 
   9 | 
  10 |
```

It appears the React does not like this line and I am unsure why. Here is the app.js file:

```
  import React from 'react';
  import PostForm from './postform.js'; 
  import PostList from './postlist'; 

  export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          posts: this.props.posts
      } 
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <PostForm />
          <PostList posts={this.state.posts}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Here is the file that is throwing the error:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import posts from './posts.json'

ReactDOM.render(<App posts={posts}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is the posts.json file that seems to be throwing the error:

```
[
    {"title": "My First Post", "author": "Jack"},
    {"title": "My Second Post", "author": "Will"},
    {"title": "My Third Post", "author": "Rick"}
]
```

Here is PostList:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import Post from './post'; 

export default class PostList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: this.props.posts
        } 
    }
    render(){
        const posts = this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
            <Post {...post} key={index} />
        }); 
        return (
            {posts}
        ); 
    }
}
```

Any help/advice would be appreciated!

Comment: according to the stack trace _"PostList (at App.js:17)"_ the problem is in `PostList` component. can you post the code for it?

Comment: added PostList to the original question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The actual error is because you're trying to use jsx-style variable insertion but there's no wrapping jsx. So you could just write `posts` or `<div>{posts}</div>`, but `{posts}` is just an object literal using the shorthand syntax, expands to `{ posts: posts }`. There are other issues like not returning from your map, but that's the explanation for the error.

Comment: That's the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your `map` function doesnt return anything:

```
const posts = this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
            <Post {...post} key={index} />
        });
```

Change it to this:

```
const posts = this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
            return <Post {...post} key={index} />
        });
```

I'm not sure on which react version you are but below V16 a component should return only one root element. so you might need to change it to this:

```
   render(){
        const posts = this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
            return <Post {...post} key={index} />
        }); 
        return (
          <div>
            {posts}
          </div>
        ); 
    }
```

Comment: May be worth noting that you can implicitly return using parentheses instead of curly braces + `return`

Comment: indeed you can, in general i'm against that when dealing with functions that should return `jsx` as sometimes you may add some logic and then your function's body can break

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive your posts object is coming in as a `collection`? I usually see this error when I have some curly braces wrapping the `collection` by mistake. React is telling you that it discovered an object with keys `{posts}`. My guess when you're importing from your `posts.json` file, it's actually coming into the app as:

```
{
  posts: [
   {"title": "My First Post", "author": "Jack"},
   {"title": "My Second Post", "author": "Will"},
   {"title": "My Third Post", "author": "Rick"}
 ]
}
```

Make sure you are passing in the **value** of `posts`, which is the collection. I tend to store constants like this in a `constants.js` file and just `export` them i.e.:

```
// constants.js
export const posts = [
    {"title": "My First Post", "author": "Jack"},
    {"title": "My Second Post", "author": "Will"},
    {"title": "My Third Post", "author": "Rick"}
]
```

Then just `import` this `collection` into your `App.js` file. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Check out this https://glitch.com/edit/#!/detailed-attack?path=src/peaks.json:1:0 I'm roughly copying their structure, and they seem to be doing it this way

Comment: Hmmm, I see what you're saying. Reading @Sag1v's answer, I think he's got it. Your `map` function should `return` something, otherwise that array will be empty.